# how to get proper printformat type for two string paramters

Tags: f#

I would like to define a printformatype type such as :

```
type DblStringPath = PrintfFormat<(string -> string-> string),unit,string,string,string>
```

In order to use like this :

```
let myValue : DblStringPath= "/%s/xxx/%s"
```

the following works like a charm :

```
type StrPath = PrintfFormat<(string -> string),unit,string,string,string>
let myValue2 : StrPath= "/aaa/bbb/%s"
```

I was thinking that the difference between `"/aaa/bbb/%s"` and `"/%s/xxx/%s"` would be `(string-> string)` vs `(string->string-> string)`

But there is an error :

> expecting a string  but here has type string *string

I then tried to change it to

```
type DblStringPath = PrintfFormat<(string * string-> string),unit,string,string,string>
```

but I have another error :

> expecting a string*string-> string but given string -> string ->
>   string

I am lost in understanding, any help would be nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second bunch of arguments are important as well, you need to use

```
type DblStringPath = PrintfFormat<(string -> string-> string),unit,string->string,string>
```

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the _why_? Looking at the [code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/37a100b7caafde0f4df5a1924c9f65f4a18277a8/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fsi#L17) it seems that the 3rd argument should be the result of the overall print action, which in this case should be `string`?

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer - not really sure about the why, but it makes everything work, so that is good enough for me